# sed command finding the lines with only matched pattern

Tags: unix, sed, command

Please suggest me regex using sed which find the lines with only the matched string .

```
/* a comment line in a C program */
#include <stdio.h>  /* including the libraries */
int main()
{
int n, i, flag = 0; /* assigning the values */

printf("Enter a positive integer: ");
scanf("%d",&n);

for(i=2; i<=n/2; ++i)
{
   /* condition for nonprime number */
    if(n%i==0)
    {
        flag=1;
        break;
    }
}

if (flag==0)
    printf("%d is a prime number.",n);
else
    printf("%d is not a prime number.",n);

return 0; /* returns 0 */
}
```

In the above text I wanted to delete the only commented lines which are not having any leading or trailing text (OR) I wanted to delete the comments which are not before or after the executable statements.

I have used `sed 's_\(/*\)\(.*\)\(*/\)_''_g' input` , but it deletes all the  comments

Please suggest the appropriate command

Comment: _" commented lines which are not having any leading or trailing text"_  Can you clarify what that means?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
sed '/^[ \t]*\/\*.*\*\/[ \t]*$/d' file
```

Deletes all commented lines having only potential leading or trailing spaces.

**Explanation:**

Applies `d` (delete) command to lines:

- `^[ \t]*`: starting with zero or more spaces or tabs
- `\/\*.*\*\/`: followed by comments. `/*` and `*/` are escaped here
- `[ \t]*$`: ending with zero or more spaces or tabs

**Edit:**

Removed an extra `^` in the second character range.

Comment: The correct solution becomes hard to read. You can make it easier to understand with `comment="\/\*.*\*\/"; sed "/^[ \t]*${comment}[^ \t]*$/d" `.

Comment: Now I can read it,  you should remove the second `^`. Lines without a space after the comment will be deleted too: `/* Test this */i=4;`

Comment: Thanks @WalterA I edited and added some more details on the command.